# Custom rules implementation is not working using SwiftLint

Tags: swift, swiftlint

I have installed **[SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint)** using [SwiftLint.pkg](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/releases/tag/0.39.2) in my system. Now I want to customize the rules so I have added **.swiftlint.yml** file in my root directory. I have added the script. I have followed the steps that are mentioned in the documentation, But somehow it's not working.

Script:

```
if which swiftlint >/dev/null; then
swiftlint --config "$SRCROOT/.swiftlint.yml"
else
echo "warning: SwiftLint not installed, download from https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint"
fi
```

Rule in .switlint.yml file :

```
custom_rules: 
comma_space_rule: 
regex: ",[ ]{2,}" 
message: "Expected only one space after ',"
```

Comment: Where exactly did you put the yml file? (`$SRCROOT` is the top-level directory of your Xcode project.)

Comment: Do no hesitate to add before other shell, like `pwd` to check where is it applied, check the existence of files etc.

Comment: Can you try via removing `--config "$SRCROOT/.swiftlint.yml"` part? You can locate .swiftlint.yml file in same directory with .xcworkspace (or .xcodeproj)

Comment: @MartinR Yes, .switlint.yml is in the top-level directory.

Comment: Is swiftlint not executed, or does it not use your custom rules? As @Larme suggested, add additional statements to your build script for debugging, for example `ls -l "$SRCROOT/.swiftlint.yml"`, and check the build log.

Comment: The variable i have mentioned as below.
`var myNameIsdefwfwefwefwef = "Jaykar,        Parmar"`
and the rule that i have mentioned in .swiftlint.yml is
`custom_rules:
comma_space_rule:
regex: ",[ ]{2,}"
message: "Expected only one space after ',"`

Comment: when i pass this `--config "$SRCROOT/.swiftlint.yml"` command i get below message.
`Loading configuration from '.swiftlint.yml'
Configuration contains invalid keys:
["message", "regex", "comma_space_rule"]
Invalid configuration for 'custom_rules'. Falling back to default.
Linting Swift files at paths 
Linting 'ViewController.swift' (1/2)
Linting 'AppDelegate.swift' (2/2)

Comment: /../AppDelegate.swift:15:1: warning: Line Length Violation: Line should be 120 characters or less: currently 145 characters (line_length)
/../AppDelegate.swift:14:1: warning: Trailing Whitespace Violation: Lines should not have trailing whitespace. (trailing_whitespace)
Done linting! Found 2 violations, 0 serious in 2 files.`

Comment: So the problem is an invalid rule or syntax error in your configuration file. You should add that rule and the error message to your question as relevant information.

Comment: @MartinR I have updated the question with the rule that i am using.

Comment: In Terminal, you run yourself SwiftLint where you put the .swiftling.yml. It might be easier to read the info in Terminal and avoid compiling each time. Now, your syntax is wrong.

Comment: If you are going to turn this into a different question then say so in the question with a reference to the comments and add any relevant errors to your question. We shouldn't have to read through all the comments to understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your rule is fine!

I tried it and it is working. You just need to indent properly:

```
custom_rules: 
        comma_space_rule:
                regex: ",[ ]{2,}"
                message: "Expected only one space after ',"
```